# Error while converting Presto SQL to Hive SQL containing subquery

Tags: sql, hive, presto

I am trying to convert the following Presto SQL to Hive SQL. The sub query in WHERE clause isn't working in Hive and is throwing an error.

```
select distinct id 
from account
where load_date = (select max(load_date) from account)
and account_status='current'
and account_type='crnt'
```

Please advise how I can fix this and make it work in Hive.

Comment: And what is an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hive doesn't support subqueries in the WHERE clause. Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id 
FROM account a
JOIN (
  SELECT max(load_date) AS max_load_date 
  FROM account
) b
ON a.load_date = b.max_load_date
WHERE a.account_status='current'
AND a.account_type='crnt';
```

or this

```
WITH max_load_date AS (
  SELECT max(load_date) AS max_date 
  FROM account
)

    SELECT DISTINCT a.id 
    FROM account a
    JOIN max_load_date m
    ON a.load_date = m.max_date
    WHERE a.account_status='current'
    AND a.account_type='crnt';
```

Comment: Thank you ! Went with second option. It worked :)